# Error occurs regarding thermal modelling of a cylindrical lithium ion battery in 3D in COMSOL Multiphysics

Tags: modeling, battery, lithium, android-ion, comsol

After running the application in the library and replace the cathode material with another material, following error occurs.

Undefined variable.

- Variable: comp1.liion.cs
- Geometry: geom1
- Domain: 3
  Failed to evaluate variable.
- Variable: comp1.liion.pce2.pin1.minput_concentration
- Defined as: comp1.liion.cs
  Failed to evaluate variable.
- Variable: comp1.liion.Ds_pce2
- Defined as: (((unit_m_cf^2)*comp1.mat1.def.DL_int1(((unit_m_cf^3)*comp1.liion.pce2.pin1.minput_concentration)/unit_mol_cf))*exp(1984.604281934087*(0.0033557046979865771084-(unit_K_cf/min(393.15,max(comp1.liion.pce2.pin1.minput_temperature,223.15))))))/unit_s_cf
  Failed to evaluate expression.
- Expression: comp1.liion.Ds_pce2
  Failed to evaluate expression.
- Expression: comp1.atonly(comp1.liion.Ds_pce2)
  Failed to evaluate expression.
- Expression: ((((d(comp1.liion.cs_pce2,xs_pce2_pin1)*(-(xs_pce2_pin1^2)))*comp1.liion.Ds_pce2)*comp1.liion.actvcorr_diff_pce2)*liion_pce2_pin1_xdim.atonly(dvol))*dvol
  Failed to evaluate Jacobian of expression.
- Expression: ((-xs_pce2_pin1^2*d(comp1.liion.cs_pce2,xs_pce2_pin1)*comp1.liion.Ds_pce2*comp1.liion.actvcorr_diff_pce2*test(d(comp1.liion.cs_pce2,xs_pce2_pin1)))*(liion_pce2_pin1_xdim.atonly(dvol)))*(dvol)

I was trying to change the cathode material in an application already exist in the application library into another material already exist in the software.